# Lombok + javac: cannot find symbol

Tags: java-8, annotations, javac, lombok, java-annotations

I'm trying to get started with Lombok. As the official [demo](https://projectlombok.org/) and the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/setup/javac) state one should be able to compile a class with lombok annotation with following simple steps:

1. Create a class and include **@Data** annotation in the code. Should be something like this

   ```
   public @Data class Test {
       private final String name;

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println(new Test("name"));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Compile with javac and **lombok.jar** put into classpath:

   ```
   javac -cp lombok.jar Test.java -verbose
   ```

Doing so unfortunately I'm running into an error:

```
Round 1:
        input files: {test.Test}
        annotations: [Data]
        last round: false
Processor lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor matches [Data] and returns false.
[parsing started lombok.javac.apt.EmptyLombokFileObject@54f47846]
[parsing completed 1ms]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/String.class)]]
Round 2:
        input files: {}
        annotations: []
        last round: false
Processor lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor matches [] and returns false.
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/Object.class)]]
[loading ZipFileIndexFileObject[C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\lib\ct.sym(META-INF/sym/rt.jar/java/lang/String.class)]]
Round 3:
        input files: {}
        annotations: []
        last round: true
Test.java:3: error: cannot find symbol
public @Data class Test {
        ^
  symbol: class Data
[total 506ms]
1 error
```

I have **javac 1.8.0_144**, **lombok 1.18.0** and running it on Windows 8.1 Pro.

Any ideas would be very helpful!

Comment: Shouldn't `@Data` be placed before `public` keyword?

Comment: @SzymonStepniak Yes, I've already tried this option but got the same error.

Comment: Check if `import lombok.Data` is present in your class. `annotations: [Data]` suggests like there is an import missing.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak, thank you. That was the cause.

Comment: @SzymonStepniak annotations are modifiers and the order of the modifiers is not relevant, so you can write `public @Data` or `@Data public`, as you like.

Answer (score 1):

The cause of compilation error was missed import:

```
import lombok.Data
```

Thanks to @SzymonStepniak who caught the problem.